# GitPython - Getting Untracked Files

Tags: python, git, gitpython

The GitPython [tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html#initialize-a-repo-object) mentions the attribute untracked_files as the way to get the array of untracked files of a particular git repository.

However referring to this attribute results in the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'Repo' object has no attribute 'untracked_files'
```

What is the method in GitPython to get the list of untracked files?

Comment: What version of GitPython are you using? The `untracked_files` property was added in 0.2 (see the [change log](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.2/changes.html#repo)).

Comment: @isedev : I had 0.1.7. Removed and installed 0.3.1-beta2. Thanks! Could you please add this comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `untracked_files` property was added in GitPython v0.2 (see the [change log](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.2/changes.html#repo)).

You should check your installed version and upgrade if necessaary.